# MySQL - record locks on query with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Engine: InnoDB
company_id is the primary key in this case. 
When I run the following sql, it locks only the rows which are selected:

```
select * from company where company_id = 1 for update
```

=> 1 row locked

```
select * from company where company_id in (1, 2) for update
```

=> 2 rows locked

But when the condition number grows to five, sqls look like these, will lock the entire table:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    company 
WHERE
    company_id = 1 
    OR company_id = 2 
    OR company_id = 3 
    OR company_id = 4 
    OR company_id = 5
FOR UPDATE
```

=> table locked

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    company 
WHERE
    company_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
FOR UPDATE
```

=> table locked

Is there any way to lock multiple records with only one query(with multiple conditions)?

===================QUESTION FIXED==============================

I'm sorry that I missed the "for update" while first editing the question.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html

Comment: how manys rows are in table 'company'?

Comment: see also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html and from http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/11/row-locking-with-mysql/ 

; This Query will not allow other transaction to
  ; Read the row with id=10
  ; It will not allow update or delete too.
  SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=10 FOR UPDATE;

Answer (score 1):

I don't think select command will lock the rows you select. According the document  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html, You should use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE to lock the rows.

Comment: According to my experiment result. If you SELECT ... FOR UPDATE more than 1 row,  MYSQL will lock the table. But, if you SELECT ... FOR UPDATE 1 row every time, MYSQL works as we think. So, please lock 1 row for one sql command. If you want to lock 3 rows,  SELECT ... FOR UPDATE 3 times.